# How to iterate through sentence of string in Python?

Tags: python, text-segmentation

Assume I have a string `text = "A compiler translates code from a source language"`. I want to do two things:

1. I need to iterate through each word and stem using the `NLTK` library. The function for stemming is `PorterStemmer().stem_word(word)`. We have to pass the argument 'word'. How can I stem each word and get back the stemmed sentence?
2. I need to remove certain stop words from the `text` string. The list containing the stop words is stored in a text file (space separated)

   ```
   stopwordsfile = open('c:/stopwordlist.txt','r+')
   stopwordslist=stopwordsfile.read()
   ```

   How can I remove those stop words from `text` and get a cleaned new string?

Comment: `for word in text.split(' '): stemmer.stem_word(word)`?

Comment: stemmed = for word in text.split(' '): stemmer.stem_word(word) will this work ?

Comment: Not exactly. If you want a list of the stems, you could do `stemmed = [stemmer.stem_word(w) for w in text.split(' ')]`. If you want a sentence of it, you can then do `sente = ' '.join(stemmed)`, which will return a sentence of all the stems. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @birryree Thanks :) I did it with " ".join(PorterStemmer().stem_word(word) for word in text.split(" "))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I posted this as a comment, but thought I might as well flesh it out into a full answer with some explanation:

You want to use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the string into words, and then stem each word:

```
for word in text.split(" "):
    PorterStemmer().stem_word(word)
```

As you want to get a string of all the stemmed words together, it's trivial to then join these stems back together. To do this easily and efficiently we use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a [generator expression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY):

```
" ".join(PorterStemmer().stem_word(word) for word in text.split(" "))
```

Edit:

For your other problem:

```
with open("/path/to/file.txt") as f:
    words = set(f)
```

Here we open the file using [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4) (which is the best way to open files, as it handles closing them correctly, even on exceptions, and is more readable) and read the contents into a set. We use a set as we don't care about the order of the words, or duplicates, and it will be more efficient later. I am presuming one word per line - if this isn't the case, and they are comma separated, or whitespace separated then using `str.split()` as we did before (with appropriate arguments) is probably a good plan.

```
stems = (PorterStemmer().stem_word(word) for word in text.split(" "))
" ".join(stem for stem in stems if stem not in words)
```

Here we use the if clause of a generator expression to ignore words that are in the set of words we loaded from a file. Membership checks on a set are O(1), so this should be relatively efficient.

Edit 2:

To remove the words before they are stemmed, it's even simpler:

```
" ".join(PorterStemmer().stem_word(word) for word in text.split(" ") if word not in words)
```

The removal of the given words is simply:

```
filtered_words = [word for word in unfiltered_words if not in set_of_words_to_filter]
```

Comment: I need to do another thing. To remove stop words from that string. List of Stopwords stored in text file (space separated)

    stopwordsfile = open('c:/stopwordlist.txt','r+')
    stopwordslist=stopwordsfile.read()

I need to remove those stop words from `text` and get cleaned new string.

Comment: @ChamingaD I would suggest that is a different problem and you should open a new question. If you do that, it will be more helpful to other people in future with a similar problem, and easier for us to work with.

Comment: Problem is i have to wait another 20 minutes to start new qustion :/

Comment: @ChamingaD I've added an answer here for this case. In future, however, posting a separate question is the better solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) can I get stopword removal as separate code ? (first i'll remove stopwords then stemming)

Comment: @ChamingaD added, in future, you might want to be clearer about what you want.

Comment: Yea, Seems my explanation is poor :/. I need two separate code segments for removing stopwords and stemming (two for loops separated). Because I have to check how each technique affect final output ;)

Comment: filtered_words = [word for word in unfiltered_words if not in set_of_words_to_filter] .. In this code unfiltered_words = text and set_of_words_to_filter = stopwordslist ? My stop word list is space separated so will this work ?

Answer (score 4):

To go through on each word in the string:

```
for word in text.split():
    PorterStemmer().stem_word(word)
```

Use string's join method (recommended by Lattyware) to concatenate pieces to one big string.

```
" ".join(PorterStemmer().stem_word(word) for word in text.split(" "))
```

Comment: The question does ask 'and get a stemmed sentence back' so a full answer would be `" ".join(PorterStemmer().stem_word(word) for word in text.split(" "))`.